# is it possible to connect to your home network from a chrome app?

Tags: javascript, vpn, google-chrome-app, openvpn

**question**
How can I package a [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/) client with a [chrome app](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/)? The app should be able to create a vpn-connection without the user having leave the chrome-app.

**more background**
I am implementing a [chrome app](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/) where a user connects to his home server via the internet. Currently I rely on [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/) to establish the connection.
Since this is not very user-friendly I was trying to find a better solution. Is it possible to **package** the openvpn client with the chrome-app? Meaning, the user only needs to enter his credentials into my app and my chrome app hands it off to **openvpn**. I did not find any such resources. Are there any other (similar secure) options?

At one point I was considering a [web-rtc p2p](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/)(e.g. via [peerjs](http://peerjs.com/)), but this would be rather awkward, since I would have to rewrite a good portion of my code.

Comment: openvpn is [open-source](http://openvpn.net/index.php/download/community-downloads.html), so it's certainly possible.  But the license is GPL, so if this is a commercial application, you probably should look elsewhere, unless you can get them to agree to commercial distribution terms.

Comment: no, its all open-source, and at this point even only in a prototype stage. But I am not quite sure if its technically possible.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be technically possible?

Comment: As far as I know openvpn is an os-depended client, while a [javascript-based] chrome-app is os-independent. I also did not see any resources/show-cases of how one could package the openvpn-client with a chrome-app.

Comment: My guess is [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) is what you are trying to achieve. May be it contains sources, if you inspect.

Comment: @robert I updated my question and it seems clear to me. Could you help me to rephrase it, since english is not my first language?

Comment: Your English is fine; you just need to ask a question that's answerable.

Comment: @sivatumma Yes, something along those lines. I will see if I can get to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Look into [Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/) for direct packaging of any native open-source project. You also might be interested in the [chrome.sockets](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html) API (that link goes to chrome.socket, but the new chrome.sockets API is better).

To repackage a product, as opposed to a library that was designed to be included in other apps, is probably a lot of work. Good luck!